# HTML auto fit to all screens

Tags: html, css

I have just Finished design an interface for a mobile app the size I used was 
750w by 1334H
the problem is its showing to big on the app testing screen

I need to auto fit the design  on all screens without losing any resolution 
here is CSS code

```css
.username {
    background: #397ba5;
    border: none;
    width: 286;
    height: 82;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24;
}
.password {
    background: #397ba5;
    border: none;
    width: 283;
    height: 81;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24;
}

.memberlogin {
    background-color: #fc4988;
    border: none;
    width: 472;
    height: 85;
    color: white;
    font-size: 40;
    font: BOLD;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled-1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://infinityfreight.net/style.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (Untitled-1.psd) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="640" height="1136" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
  <td colspan="7">
   <img src="http://infinityfreight.net/images/Untitled-1_01.gif" width="750" height="508" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="3" rowspan="4">
   <img src="http://infinityfreight.net/images/Untitled-1_02.gif" width="324" height="264" alt=""></td>
  <td colspan="3">
   <input type=text class="username"></td>
  <td rowspan="8">
   <img src="http://infinityfreight.net/images/Untitled-1_04.gif" width="140" height="826" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="3">
   <img src="http://infinityfreight.net/images/Untitled-1_05.gif" width="286" height="49" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2">
   <input type=password class="password"></td>
  <td rowspan="2">
   <img src="http://infinityfreight.net/images/Untitled-1_07.gif" width="3" height="133" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2">
   <img src="http://infinityfreight.net/images/Untitled-1_08.gif" width="283" height="52" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
   <img src="http://infinityfreight.net/images/Untitled-1_09.gif" width="138" height="124" alt=""></td>
  <td colspan="4">
   <input type="submit" value="SIGN IN NOW" class="memberlogin"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="4">
   <img src="http://infinityfreight.net/images/Untitled-1_11.gif" width="472" height="39" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="2">
   <img src="http://infinityfreight.net/images/Untitled-1_12.gif" width="130" height="438" alt=""></td>
  <td colspan="3">
   <a href="/">
   <img src="http://infinityfreight.net/images/Untitled-1_13.gif" width="318" height="29" alt=""></a></td>
  <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
   <img src="http://infinityfreight.net/images/Untitled-1_14.gif" width="162" height="438" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="3">
   <img src="http://infinityfreight.net/images/Untitled-1_15.gif" width="318" height="409" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <img src="http://infinityfreight.net/images/spacer.gif" width="130" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://infinityfreight.net/images/spacer.gif" width="8" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://infinityfreight.net/images/spacer.gif" width="186" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://infinityfreight.net/images/spacer.gif" width="124" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://infinityfreight.net/images/spacer.gif" width="159" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://infinityfreight.net/images/spacer.gif" width="3" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="140" height="1" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: DId not fix the problem

Answer (score 2):

In order to make your app rescale for each screen size you need to use media queries. An example of a media query is this,

**MIN-WIDTH**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 330px)  {...}
```

Here's what that actually means:

"If `[device width]` is greater than or equal to `[specified #]`, then do `{...}`"

So if the actual "`device width`" is `320px` this condition will return false.

"If `320px` is greater than or equal to `330px`, then do `{...}`"

**MAX-WIDTH**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 330px)  {...}
```

Translates to:

"If `[device width]` is less than or equal to `[specified #]`, then do `{...}`"

So based on this second example, if the "`device width`" is `320px` the condition is true:

"If `320px` is less than or equal to `330px`, then do `{...}`"

**Alternative - Use Twitter Bootstrap**

My favorite way to handle developing responsive apps is to use `Twitter Bootstrap`

> Bootstrap comes out of the box mobile friendly and responsive. Bootstrap is a free and open-source front-end web framework for
>   designing websites and web applications. It contains HTML- and
>   CSS-based design templates for typography, forms, buttons, navigation
>   and other interface components, as well as optional JavaScript
>   extensions.

You can find [Twitter Bootstrap here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/)

Also your code is not defining the height and width properly. Please see the updated code.

```
.username {
    background: #397ba5;
    border: none;
    width: 286px;
    height: 82px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24;
}
.password {
    background: #397ba5;
    border: none;
    width: 283px;
    height: 81px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24;
}

.memberlogin {
    background-color: #fc4988;
    border: none;
    width: 472px;
    height: 85px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 40;
    font: BOLD;
}
```

You can also use percents.

```
width: 20%;
```

Ok I understand. You do not have basic knoledge of css. I am going to try to give you one more example. You are not implementing media queries correctly. Here is an example.

Media queries do not wrap all of your css. You make css rules. Then when certain rules need to change based on the different screen sizes you create a media query and drop that specific rule that needs to change inside of it. Here is an example.

I am going to change the width of a `div` on screen sizes that are smaller that `100px` Please take special notice to the `px`. This is how we designate a size. in a lot of cases - but not all cases we use `px`.

In this example notice we create `.div1` then we create a media query and place the class `div1` in it with a different width.

```
.div1 {
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
  color: black;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 330px)  {
 .div1 {
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  color: black;
}  
}
```

**The Output of This**

Example one. Default css output,
[image]

Example two. With the media query a screen size under `100px`.
[image]

Notice the width of the div is different based on the size of the screen.

Comment: Great explantion but I am new to this I don't know how to do it can you fix the code for me that way I have an idea how you did it ?

Comment: You should code and do the work.. not us.... this is not a page for teaching beginners how to program. Check the rules please.

Comment: @Nick there is so much to do to make your app work it is impossible for any of us to do it for you with a little code. We can only answer small questions. You are not defining the width and height of your elements correctly. You need to go back to the basics and take the time to learn.  When you have another question format it correctly and we will help you. try and ask small questions and not questions like this as broad as how to make my whole site work a certain way. Let me know if I can do anything else for you buddy. till then accept my answer and use it to learn. Use google too.

Comment: To be clear. Fixing your problem cant be done with a line of code. You need to add a lot. So you must read and learn

Comment: **LEARN** Not searching for someone to fix your problem based on the lack of basic css knowledge

Comment: I am not trying to make you guys code for me. No one has answered my question. I did not ask anyone to code it for me he provided an expiation and it seems like he know what to do. Also where is the problem I didn't set me width and heights right?? okay show me how to set them right?? and @wuno yes I would actually want you to answer the question that I asked? your answer was just telling me to be on my own and search stuff up? I searched things up and I couldn't find solution that's why I posted a question here. Please if anyone know a solve to the problem or what changes need to be done.

Comment: I literally took your css and added the correct width and height to my answer. Look at the difference in my answer. look anywhere it says width and notice the px at the end of it.

Comment: @NICK once again. It is impossible for us to fix your website only with the broken css you showed in your question. But I added more examples of using media queries to the bottom of my answer for you. Please try and understand it. Also make sure to update your css with the correct width and height attributes, for example adding px. I hope this helps. I suggest you ask your parents to buy you a course on css or web development from Udemy.

Answer (score 0):

Responsive design is generally preferred, but you can do what I think you want with

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320" />
```

where 320 is the number of pixels in the view (device independent).

See http://www.html5hacks.com/blog/2012/11/28/elegantly-resize-your-page-with-the-at-viewport-css-declaration/

Comment: Did not fix the problem

Answer (score -1):

Use the CSS rule [@media](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp). There you can code styles to be used when the min screen width is X.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .username {
        background: #397ba5;
        border: none;
        width: 286;
        height: 82;
        color: white;
        font-size: 24;
    }
    .password {
        background: #397ba5;
        border: none;
        width: 283;
        height: 81;
        color: white;
        font-size: 24;
    }    

    .memberlogin {
        background-color: #fc4988;
        border: none;
        width: 472;
        height: 85;
        color: white;
        font-size: 40;
        font: BOLD;
    }
}
```

Comment: CSS stopped working when adding @media screen and (min-width: 480px)

Comment: I place it on the code and works, so check what you are doing wrong, and check how to use @media. I put a link in the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy but if you please take a look on the HTML code every picture has its own Width and heights except for the Inputs I am using CSS for them. Note I have been using adobe Photoshop To designee and cut them. and every time I finish designing I have this problem with the resolution